# Multithreading performance of QtConcurrent Vs QThread with many threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread, qtconcurrent

Suppose your application needs to run a function in multiple threads the number of which is more than the number of CPU cores/threads. One way is to use `QtConcurrent` and setting the maximum thread count :

```
MyClass *obj = new MyClass;

QThreadPool::globalInstance()->setMaxThreadCount(30);

for(int i=0;i<30;i++)
    QtConcurrent::run(obj, &MyClass::someFunction);
```

Another way is to have multiple objects and move them to different threads using `moveToThread` :

```
for(int i=0;i<30;i++)
{
        MyClass *obj = new MyClass;
        QThread *th = new QThread();
        obj->moveToThread(th);
        connect(th, SIGNAL(started()), obj, SLOT(someFunction()) );
        connect(obj, SIGNAL(workFinished()), th, SLOT(quit()) );
        connect(th, SIGNAL(finished()), obj, SLOT(deleteLater()) );
        connect(th, SIGNAL(finished()), th, SLOT(deleteLater()) );

        th->start();
}
```

As the number of threads are more than the number of CPU cores, the threads should be switched between different cores when running.

The question is whether the two approaches have different performances or not? i.e does switching of a `QThread` differ from one that is run using `QtConcurrent::run` ?

Comment: It depends on what each thread does.  Rule of thumb: for CPU bound threads more threads than cores will decrease overall performance; for I/O bound threads it is possible to have more threads than available cores.  You need to measure.

Comment: @RichardCritten You are right, but the question here is the difference between `QtConcurrent` and `QThread`in switching time.

Comment: Depends on your use case. As always, measure to see if it makes a difference in your situation. QConcurrent is convenience around QThreads, the differences will lie in how the tasks are scheduled and resources utilized, not in context switching times as such. Writing your own solution will give your more flexibility but of course also more work and more bugs.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld But here all of the resource utilization,  scheduling, .. are the same as 30 threads are running the same function. Only the approach of starting the threads are different. So I think the only difference would be how context switching differ between the two.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I agree with first answer, but I want to add something.

`QThread` is low-level class which just run OS-specific functions. What is the `QtConcurrent`? The answer is in `Qt` source code.

First level: [run](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrentrun.html)

```
QFuture<T> run(T (*functionPointer)())  
{
        return (new StoredFunctorCall0<T, T (*)()>(functionPointer))->start();
}
```

[Second](https://github.com/Vitallium/qt5/blob/master/qtbase/src/concurrent/qtconcurrentstoredfunctioncall.h#L58):

```
struct StoredFunctorCall0: public RunFunctionTask<T>    { ...
```

[Third](https://github.com/Vitallium/qt5/blob/master/qtbase/src/concurrent/qtconcurrentrunbase.h#L74):

```
template <typename T>
class RunFunctionTaskBase : public QFutureInterface<T> , public QRunnable
{ ...
```

Now about `QRunnable`. When we start `QRunnable` with `QThreadPool` we do:

[start()](https://github.com/Vitallium/qt5/blob/master/qtbase/src/corelib/thread/qthreadpool.cpp#L442) which calls `tryStart()` which calls `startThread()` which operate with `QThreadPoolThread` (and it is a [QThread subclass](https://github.com/Vitallium/qt5/blob/master/qtbase/src/corelib/thread/qthreadpool.cpp#L57)) and it is finally call `start()` of `QThread`.

And of course this chain is not full, long road, isn't it? So as I know, when we use abstraction, we have abstraction penalty (`QtConcurrent` has bigger penalty then `QThread`), but final result is same, it is `QThread`.

Comment: Thanks. So if they are all `QThread`s I guess there is not much difference between the two after they have started running.

Answer (score 11):

Short answer: it depends on the nature/logic of the workload.

[QtConcurrent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrent-index.html) runs a pool of threads and it is a higher level API **not well-suited to run a large number of blocking operations**: if you do a lot of blocking operations you will soon end up draining the pool and having other requests queued. In that case [QThread](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html) (a lower level construct) is probably better suited for the operation (each one represents a single thread).

Comment: In the example i provided, the maximum number of threads in thread pool is set to a bigger number, so it would not be drained and all of the threads are run without queuing. Also the nature/logic of the process of the two approaches are the same and they are running the same piece of code.

Comment: @Nejat The 'large number' is with respect to that maximum number you set. The nature of the workload is not specified in this question so there isn't enough info to provide any analysis. You'll have to benchmark it yourself.